# Naming variables "_t3" from LinearSolve output in Maple 17

Tags: maple

When I, in Maple 17, use LinearSolve in the package LinearAlgebra I get an result like

```
<3_t3,_t3,-2_t3>
```

Is it possible to tell Maple to name the variable _t3 something else? I want it to be named just "t" or something.

Can I collect the variable, so the result would be something like

```
_t3 * <3,1,-2>
```

I guess it's called standard parametric form. I've tried `collect(%,_t3)`, but it does not do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question: Yes, simply include the option **free= t** in your **LinearSolve** call.

I'll have to think on your second question for a while.